# How to generically produce iterators (to loop over many variables)

Tags: iterators

A generalization of, for example:

```
Do[(* stuff *), {x, listx},{y, listy},{z, listz}]
```

I can almost do this with Table, but I need a way to flatten the outer brackets:

```
Table[{s, l[s]}, {s, {x, y, z}}]  

(* out: {{x, l[x]},{y, l[y]},{z,l[z]}}
```

But to use this List, I need really to exchange the outerbrackets to simply a sequence.

If I append to the end

```
/.List->Sequence
```

It will remove all of the brackets and not give the desired result. Similar issues plague

```
Flatten
FlattenAt[ ,1]
```

etc. solutions.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: What is your desired result? because if `Sequence[{x, l[x]},...]` then you can just `f @@ result` and do not care about those very outer brackets. It is unclear to me what you are after. `Table` and `Do` are different in fundamental way. `Do`, unless forced, is not producing any output. If you need you can use it with `Sow`/`Reap`

Comment: Do[Print[{x,y,z}],{x,Range[0.1,0.9,0.1]},{y,Range[0.1,0.9,0.1]},{z,Range[0.1,0.9,0.1]}]

Comment: But I would like to be able to shorten this to something like:Do[Print[{x,y,z}],{x,y,z}@Range[0.1,0.9,0.1]] or whatever, some kind of easily generalizable way for more variables

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your query, you're looking for something like:

```
myNestedLoop[range_, vars_] := 
            Sequence @@ Transpose[{vars, ConstantArray[range, Length@vars]}]

Table[{a, b, c}, Evaluate@myNestedLoop[Range[3, 9, 3], {a, b, c}]]

(*
{{{{3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 6}, {3, 3, 9}}, {{3, 6, 3}, {3, 6, 6}, {3, 6, 
    9}}, {{3, 9, 3}, {3, 9, 6}, {3, 9, 9}}}, {{{6, 3, 3}, {6, 3, 
    6}, {6, 3, 9}}, {{6, 6, 3}, {6, 6, 6}, {6, 6, 9}}, {{6, 9, 3}, {6,
     9, 6}, {6, 9, 9}}}, {{{9, 3, 3}, {9, 3, 6}, {9, 3, 9}}, {{9, 6, 
    3}, {9, 6, 6}, {9, 6, 9}}, {{9, 9, 3}, {9, 9, 6}, {9, 9, 9}}}}
*)
```

You can stack as needed:

```
Table[{a, b, c, d}, Evaluate@myNestedLoop[Range[2, 4, 2], {a, b}], 
                    Evaluate@myNestedLoop[Range[3, 5, 2], {c, d}]]

(*
{{{{{2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 3, 5}}, {{2, 2, 5, 3}, {2, 2, 5, 5}}}, {{{2, 
     4, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 3, 5}}, {{2, 4, 5, 3}, {2, 4, 5, 5}}}}, {{{{4, 
     2, 3, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 5}}, {{4, 2, 5, 3}, {4, 2, 5, 5}}}, {{{4, 4, 
     3, 3}, {4, 4, 3, 5}}, {{4, 4, 5, 3}, {4, 4, 5, 5}}}}}
*)
```

Arguments can be lists created elsewhere of course.

As alluded to in comments, not sure of the utility of such a construct (I suppose if one had a gazillion loop variables with large common sets of bounds it saves some typing), perhaps some more concrete examples of your desired end-result might elicit a better way to accomplish it overall...

Comment: I appreciate your effort, and yeah, I guess it's just an attempt to save some typing. In the past, I've often noticed that when I find myself typing the same thing over and over, there is usually a more elegant way to formulate it. But writing ", {a, Range[d, 1 - d, d]}, {t, Range[d, 1 - d, d]}, {g, 
 Range[d, 1 - d, d]}, {v, Range[d, 1 - d, d]}, {V, Range[d, 1 - d, d]}" isn't really that bad, I guess